# Why current command result in exit of previous command?

Tags: bash

In my .bashrc

```
alias ss="sudo sh -c '/usr/bin/nohup /usr/local/bin/sslocal -c /etc/ss.json > /var/log/ss.log 2>&1' & "
```

Run ss at the first time.

```
debian9@hwy:~/workspace$ ss
[1] 9710
```

Run ss at the second time

```
debian9@hwy:~/workspace$ ss
[2] 9728
[1]   Exit 1                  sudo sh -c '/usr/bin/nohup /usr/local/bin/sslocal -c /etc/ss.json > /var/log/ss.log 2>&1'
```

The second command result in exit of the first command.
Why?
Now run command `cd`

```
debian9@hwy:~/workspace$ cd
[2]+  Exit 1                  sudo sh -c '/usr/bin/nohup /usr/local/bin/sslocal -c /etc/ss.json > /var/log/ss.log 2>&1'  (wd: ~/workspace)
(wd now: ~)
```

Why `cd` result in exit of `ss` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just the impression you get because your shell only outputs information on completed jobs when it outputs a prompt; quoting *e.g.* the [`bash` manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#JOB_CONTROL):

> The shell learns immediately whenever a job changes state. Normally, `bash` waits until it is about to print a prompt before reporting changes in a job's status so as to not interrupt any other output. If the `-b` option to the `set` builtin command is enabled, `bash` reports such changes immediately. Any trap on `SIGCHLD` is executed for each child that exits.

So what’s happening is

1. You start `ss` which runs in the background.
2. The shell outputs the next prompt.
3. The background job finishes, but the shell doesn’t output anything yet.
4. You run your next command (anything, `ss`, `cd` etc.).
5. The shell outputs the next prompt, and since it’s doing so, outputs the exit information for completed jobs...

You can see what’s really happening by running `set -b` so the shell won’t wait for a prompt before outputting a completed job’s exit status.